# Can HDFS files be modified?

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs

I recently overheard a conversation where someone said HDFS files could not be modified.

I was surprised to hear that as I thought all file operations including updating were supported. Now I know that HDFS is optimized for streaming but is this related to permissions, or is modification strictly not allowed?

N.B. I am referring to modification and not appending of data to existing files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDFS is an append only filesystem. To "update" a file requires you to collect all blocks of a file, rewrite their content, then update all block locations

HDFS also is not optimized for streaming. That is why frameworks like Kafka, Storm, Spark, Flink, Samza, NiFi, etc. all exist. They *integrate* with Hadoop, but streaming small batches of files into HDFS is not what it is optimized for.

Not sure I understood the comment about permissions, but those are controlled by Namenode ACLs or external systems such as Ranger or Sentry.

If instead you're referring to ACID Transactions on Hive tables, then that's typically where you use the phrase "CRUD operations".